# data-dismiss not dismissing Bootstrap modal when used together with click event binding, disabled binding, and validation in Angular app

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4.1 to create a bug tracking app in Angular 6. This setup has worked before in the same app built in earlier versions of everything. But I'm rebuilding it with latest versions.

```
<button            
  class="btn btn-success btn-xl"
  type="submit"
  data-dismiss="modal"
  (click)="submitForm()"
  [disabled]="bugForm.invalid">
  Save
</button>
```

The modal contains a form for entering new bugs. There seems to be three pieces involved in the problem: click event binding, disabled binding, and validation. I can make data-dismiss work by either: 1) removing the click event binding, 2) removing the disabled binding, or 3) commenting out the Validators.required (below) applied in the .ts file to bug properties entered in the form.

```
this.bugForm = this.formB.group({
  title: [this.currentBug.title, 
    [Validators.required, forbiddenStringValidator(/bug/i)]],
  status: [this.currentBug.status, Validators.required],
  severity: [this.currentBug.severity, Validators.required],
  description: [this.currentBug.description, Validators.required]
});
```

Performing any one of those three actions while leaving the other two intact allows data-dismiss to work perfectly. And with all three left intact, everything besides data-dismiss works: the button is only enabled when all fields are valid, and clicking it causes the new bug to be added to the bug list and entered in the database, but the modal won't go away.

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing the conflict? There are no console errors.

For the record, I replaced the Bootstrap classes with "close", per Bootstrap's documentation, but that didn't help. And using "close" with Bootstrap classes kills the styles.

Comment: The data attribute is jQuery and you shouldn't use jQuery in Angular 6. Take a look at the ng bootstrap modal documentation. It will show you how to implement it in TypeScript. I was trying the same approach as you until I ran across the correct documentation: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: Thanks. I don't see the ng-bootstrap version of the grid, which I rely heavily on. The ng-bootstrap website is not exactly explicit about this, but it seems that I should eliminate my dependency on bootstrap.js, as well as popper and jquery, but that I should maintain my dependency on bootstrap.css for implementation of the grid. Aside from that, it looks like I will have to rebuild my modal, and whatever other features require JavaScript, the ng-bootstrap way. Does this sound right to you?

Comment: You should build typescript components for each area of the modal (header, footer, body) and then render them appropriately (<modal-header></modal-header><modal-body></modal-body>) inside your html file. You can still use the css files, just try to avoid using JS or jQuery. Grid? I've used Angular DataTables (uses jQuery) and Bootstrap pagination in the past. I would recommend Bootstrap pagination because filtering and sorting is very expensive and you want to limit the call backs to the server. Remember, the key is to conserve people's data plans!!

Comment: I'm confused by your assertion that I shouldn't use jQuery, and by implication some features of Bootstrap, with Angular 6. I haven't encountered this anywhere else. It implies that I have to be selective what Bootstrap elements I use in my app, and if they require anything but CSS, I have to find another way to build them. Is there a resource you can point me to that would fill me in on the when, why, how, what, etc. regarding Angular and Bootstrap becoming incompatible with each other? I'm just kind of shocked by this because I've been learning Bootstrap thinking it was solid with Angular.

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't use jQuery. I was referring to in-line attributes and events such as click, for example. jQuery: <input type="button" click="myFunction()"> Angular: <input type="button" (click)="myFunction()">